# Django clean field model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Is it necessary to clean the fields in views or just in forms.py?

How does the clean method work in `ModelForm`?

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)


class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['name', 'authors']
   
   def clean_name(self):
       pass


def create(request):
    if request.method == 'post':
        form = Bookform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        #there itc necessary to do: 
        book.name = form.cleaned_data['name'] ?
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "call the fields"?

Comment: if form.is_valid():
       
        book = form.save(commit=False)
         #there itc necessary to do:
         book.name = form.cleaned_data['name']

Answer (score 0):

cleaned_data or Clean() can only be used after form data is validated (e.g after form.is_valid()) Not necessary but enforcing validation is best practice. So cleaned_data can and should only be nested inside of a is_valid or similar check.

Check out docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/